# Javascript | How to split one semi-random number into three random numbers, whose additive value add to initial number

Tags: javascript, math

My goal: Given a specific rgb value such as (215, 183, 71), I want to generate a random number between 20-30, and divide that number into three additive parts that add to the initial number. From there, each number should be subtracted from their respective color value, from a specified color.

Unless I'm lacking a significant amount of brainpower currently, this seems like it requires a somewhat creative solution, which is why I leave it in the hands of whomever may read this.

E.G:

```
var colorDifference=27;
var RGB=rgb(100-differenceR,100-differenceG,100-differenceB,1);

function colorDiffValues(){ 
 differenceR=5;
 differenceG=13;
 differenceB=9;
}
```

However, clearly not with those exact value. so it would have to be something such as

```
var colorDiff= random number between 20 to 30
var RGB=rgb(r-diffR, g-diffG,b-diffB);

function colorDiffValues(){
 diffR= random value
 diffG= random value
 diffB= random value
// where diffR+diffG+diffB=colorDiff
// AND diffR,diffG, and diffB are all positive numbers.
}
```

goodnight!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant logic that would split a random value intro three random values. You only need to specify what is the minimum value for each of the three numbers.

```
<script>

// get random number between 20 and 30
let colorDifference = 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

// defines the smallest value for each of the generated numbers
// if set to 3, then 25 split into 10, 2, 13 wouldn't be valid as one of them is lower than 3
let smallestValue = 3;

// generate numbers
let totalRange = colorDifference;
let numberOne = smallestValue + Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalRange - 3*smallestValue));
totalRange -= numberOne;
let numberTwo = smallestValue + Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalRange - 2*smallestValue));
let numberThree = colorDifference - (numberOne + numberTwo);

console.log('Value ' + colorDifference + ' was split into ' + numberOne + ',' + numberTwo + ', ' + numberThree);
</script>
```

Here you have an example where I use it to paint a div with a random color:

```
<div class="box" id="original"></div>
<div class="box" id="generated"></div>

<span id="result"></span>

<style>
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<script>

// values for original
let red = 200;
let green = 200;
let blue = 200;

// get random number between 20 and 30
let colorDifference = 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

// defines the smallest value for each of the generated numbers
// if set to 3, then 25 split into 10, 2, 13 wouldn't be valid as one of them is lower than 3
let smallestValue = 3;

// generate numbers
let totalRange = colorDifference;
let numberOne = smallestValue + Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalRange - 3*smallestValue));
totalRange -= numberOne;
let numberTwo = smallestValue + Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalRange - 2*smallestValue));
let numberThree = colorDifference - (numberOne + numberTwo);

// generate colors
let newRed = red - numberOne;
let newGreen = green - numberTwo;
let newBlue = blue - numberThree;

// set colors
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = colorDifference + ' split into ' + numberOne + ', ' + numberTwo + ', ' + numberThree;
document.getElementById('original').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba('+red+','+green+','+blue+',1)';
document.getElementById('generated').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba('+newRed+','+newGreen+','+newBlue+',1)';
</script>
```